# I used react-native-vision-camera in my project and got this error:

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Confeez-Workspace\Demo\node_modules\react-native-vision-camera\android\build.gradle' line: 231
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-vision-camera'.

> Expected directory 'D:\Confeez-Workspace\Demo\node_modules/react-native/android' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have 'react-native-reanimated' installed in your project as well?)

Comment: This is known issue and you need to wait for update
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1418

Comment: The new version `2.15.31 was released with a fix. Please try
More info here https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/pull/1438